Image Generation Models
I am looking for a list of different image generation models and how I can test them? For example:
DALL-E (accessible via ChatGPT4)
Stable Diffusion (open source)
CLIP? - but idk how to access/test it.
What other competitors exist that one can easily test on a macbook?

CLIP is available via Huggingface. However, I will warn you, that CLIP is not an image generation model, it is used more for multimodal supervised tasks (i.e. have a text and image prompt for image classification or image retrieval). DALL-E and Stable Diffusion are autoencoder-based architectures (self-supervised learning models that learn to generate things similar to its training set).

Are there any other i could use for comparison? @AndrewJaeyoung

No other general-purpose image gen model that I know of. There's different text-to-image models out there trained for different purposes, but these are all effectively stable diffusion with a different training set and slightly different architectures.
